# Why do my transparent dialogs appear glitchy, and for those unfortunate enough to have seizures... cause problems?

Tags: unity, intel-graphics

The screenshots here show what I mean by glitchy:
Side note: I'm using a laptop from 2006, with integrated 945GM graphics, so that's probably my problem.
[image: Glitchy shutdown dialog]

[image: The dash]

[image: Unreadable shortcut dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to install unity-tweak-tool, `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`, go into Unity>Search and change Background Blur to OFF. You can also use CCSM to change this setting by going into desktop>unity plugin, and changing Dash Blur to No Blur.